# Is there a way to use Handlebars.js to inject a template using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I am using Big Commerce/Stencil CLI and I am inside of a javascript file trying to target elements by their class and inject a handlebars template into it's HTML and I haven't been able to find much on this topic. This code appears to throw an "Error: Module build failed" In one of my theme-bundle.chunk files.

My code:

```
if (el.getAttribute('data-swatch-0') !== null) {
        $(".category-swatch-container").innerHTML({{{ > components/ud-custom/ud-category-swatches}}});
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. At its most basic handlebars takes a template string and params, then produces a output string.  The jQuery html method can accept a string of valid html and insert it.

The problem here is it looks like you are trying to do this substitution on the backend. You can make this work but it is an unusual configuration and probably needs to be explicitly added. You need to tell your backend to treat a request to the js file to execute the file as a handlebars template. Depending on your backend framework this may be as easy as adding a config option or you may need to add an explicit route that produces the js file.

If you want to do this client side you need to make sure you have added handlebars as a client side dependency. Then you just need to make the template available on the client side.  Then you can invoke the handlebars library directly to produce a String that can be fed to $.html